# NsUserNotification: Elide a title at the beginning instead of the end

Tags: objective-c, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

All three of [title](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSUserNotification/title), subtitle and informativeText elide their content if it's too long to be displayed. All of them elide them at the end.

Is there away to elide it at the beginning? This would be useful for example when trying to display a long domain.

An alternative solution which would also work is some way to get the available space of all these three properties so the NSString(s) can be elided prior to setting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no API support for either—sounds like a good candidate for an [enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com). Given that there currently isn’t a way to adjust the font size in notifications, you can probably get away with a manual version of the second approach for now; you’ll just have to do some experimentation to find reasonable truncation lengths for each field.